# UnetStack - Physical parameters

Tags: unetstack

I am looking to explore these three physical parameters:-

1.phy[].fec

2.phy[].feclist

3.phy[].errorDetection

where can i get detailed information including implementation as well?

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can type `help` followed by the name of the parameter (e.g. `help phy[].fec`) to get more information about that parameter.

The PHY parameters are dependent on the specific modem implementation. You can type `phy[CONTROL].fecList` and `phy[DATA].fecList` to get a list of forward error correction (FEC) codes available in your modem.

For more information, you should contact your modem manufacturer.